# How to make an interface object Java

Tags: java

For my CS class I am required to use some premade code and use the interface in my spreadsheet. I have a few classes already, Program, SpreadSheet, PersistanceHelper and an interface Savable.

```
 package persistence;

    public interface Savable {
        public String[] getSaveData();
        public void loadFrom(String[] saveData);
    }


    package persistence;

    import java.io.*;
    import java.util.*;

    public class PersistenceHelper {

    public static void save(String filePath, Savable toSave) throws Exception {

        String[] data = toSave.getSaveData();

        PrintStream out = new PrintStream(new File(filePath));

        try {
            for (String datum : data) {
                out.println(datum);
            }
        } finally {
            out.close();
        }
    }

    public static void load(String filePath, Savable toLoadTo) throws Exception {
        ArrayList<String> data = new ArrayList<String>();

        Scanner input = new Scanner(new File(filePath));

        try {
            while (input.hasNextLine()) {
                data.add(input.nextLine());
            }
        } finally {
            input.close();
        }

        String[] dataArray = new String[data.size()];
        toLoadTo.loadFrom(data.toArray(dataArray));
    }

}
```

//These are this class and interface I am not allowed to change and I am required to use the save and load methods in the PersistanceHelper and am struggling to create a variable of the Savable type.

Comment: you did not state a question.

Answer (score 0):

An `interface` simply describes how a class behaves externally. To get an instance, it must know how to retrieve results from declared functions, specified by the **implementation**:

```
public class MySavable implements Savable {
    public String[] getSaveData() {
        // some code
        return whatever;
    }

    public void loadFrom(String[] saveData) {
        // some code
    }
}
```

You can then do things like:

```
Savable s = new MySavable();
String[] strings = s.getSaveData();
s.loadFrom(strings);
```

Answer (score 0):

Implement the savable interface class , by child class say savableImpl. And that object you use with this interface.

Isn't it whole point of having interface.

```
public class SavableImpl implements Savable{
public String[] getSaveData(){
 // implementation goes here
}
public void loadFrom(String[] saveData){
  // implementation here
}
```

}

Then you can go like this :-

```
Savable savable = new SavableImpl();
```

I am pretty sure, whoever designed existing class , meant same to be done .

Comment: Seems i posted answer same as above one. however it is only answer for this question.